"Define current document as 'Master Document'." in VSCode
In TexMaker there is an option that is:
"Define current document as 'Master Document'."
Which is very helpful when editing a multiple-files document. However, I recently switched to VSCode and could not find an equivalent option or command.
Does VSCode have such a possibility?
Thank you all.

You can see the wiki, which says: "While it is fine to write all contents in one .tex file, it is common to split things up for simplicity. For such LaTeX projects, the file with \documentclass[]{} is considered as the root file, which serves as the entry point to the project. LaTeX Workshop intelligently finds the root file when a new document is opened, the active editor is changed, or any LaTeX Workshop command is executed."

Thank you @zpding, I did not have a problem with that point, VSCode does find the main file. Usually, when there is only one file, this file is compiled whenever I save it, but when I am editing an included file in its own window and save it, I have to go back to the main-file window to compile it, in TexMaker you do not need to do that , just click the compile button and the main file will be compiled even if the active window is for included file, not the main file. I hope I explained it right

Supposing that you are using the LaTeX Workshop extension, you can find all the information you need in its wiki, specifically in this page.
I am using "Magic comments", which I find self-explanatory and are supported by many editors. At the top of your "child" file you put a line
% !TEX root = relative/or/absolute/path/to/root/file.tex

and the editor takes care of the rest.
Note: With LaTeX Workshop you need to change a setting for this to work, as described in the wiki page. Specifically, set latex-workshop.latex.build.forceRecipeUsage to false.
Then you can use magic comments also on your main file, to specify the engine (pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex) used, the bibliography engine (bibtex, biber) used, etc.

Thank you very much @nplatis, this solved it.
